# Where I find the saved file in iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a problem for saving pdf file on iPhone.

I have used the following objective c code to save pdf file:

```
    NSURL *pathURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    NSString *filePath = [pathURL.path
                      stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"filname.pdf"];

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath
                                            contents:pdfdata
                                          attributes:nil];
```

I can check whether the file is saved or not correctly using webview.
I can check the contents of the saved pdf file using webview.

But I can't find the saved file on both simulator and device.

Where can I find my saved file on iPhone?

If anyone knows the solution for my issue then please advise me.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you having issues finding and/or opening the saved file from your code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I mean can't find the saved pdf file on iPhone file browser like on Android phone. If we save a file to a folder on an android phone then we can find it on the android file browser later. But on iPhone, I can't see any files which I saved.

Comment: Your not really supposed to browse the iPhone file system and if the code works fine why would you need to? As mentioned in the answer below you can do it when using the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Your .pdf file was saved in your application document folder. So, You can easily check on simulator. Like below

Print a downloaded file path

`print(filePath)`

then go to

> Finder -> Go Menu -> Go to folder

and paste the filePath

[image]

This is the path of your application document folder

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. And your case is for a simulator. So I can find the saved files on my computer. But how to find that files on the iPhone? And how to do the case for a real device? If I use my iPhone, then I can't find saved file on my iPhone.

Comment: We can't able to find a file saved on device. If the code is working fine in simulator. No worry It will also work on iPhone